# Validation doesn't work for second form in controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller with 2 functions, each with a form being generated and passed through to a view.

The first is for a users profile and picks up the Validation.yml file perfectly - checking that the name and email are not blank.

In the same validation file I have set Password to not be blank.

However, the second form, which will allow a user to change their password, doesn't want to validate.

The second form is basically a copy of the first, but with two fields, "password" and "confirmPassword".

Surely as my field is called "password" it should match the variable in my User entity? (this is what is happening for the first form)

Some code:

passwordAction

```
    public function passwordAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('password', null, array('label' => 'New Password'))
                ->add('confirmPassword', null, array('label' => 'Confirm Password'))
                ->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

                //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dashboard'));
            }

        }

        return $this->render('UserBundle:Dashboard:password.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

password form twig: (nb - the novalidate is to rturn off html5 validation!!)

```
<form action="{{ path('update_password') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Change Your Password</legend>
        {{ form_row(form.password) }}
        {{ form_row(form.confirmPassword) }}
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="actions">
            <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Update" />
            <input class="btn error" type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

validation.yml:

```
UserBundle\Entity\Profile:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~

UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        email:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Email:
                message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
                checkMX: true
        password:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

routing.yml:

```
password:
    pattern: /password
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Dashboard:password }

update_password:
    pattern: /password
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Dashboard:password }
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not configured any data_class option in your form,
neither put any data in your form, using `$form->setData($user);` for example.

The validator does not match anything to validate because there is no `UserBundle\Entity\User`  object to validate.

What you should do is:

```php
 $user = new UserBundle\Entity\User; // or fetch it from database.

 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
     ->add('password', 'repeated')
     ->getForm()
 ;
 $form->setData($user);
```

This way, when you will bind new data to your form and validate it, it will know that your are trying to validate a `UserBundle\Entity\User` object.

*You will notice I modified your code to use a `repeated` field type, that do exactly what you want.*

Comment: Haha, yea I kind of figured it out not long after, but thank you very much for answering :)